# How do you say 'dates back to' in Mandarin?

Tags: mandarin, grammar

What is the best way of expressing 'dates back to' in Mandarin? e.g. the family's lineage dates back to 1720..etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Dates back to' is usually translated into '追溯到', which literally means 'trace back to'.

When used in a sentence, people usually add 可以 (can/may) or 要 (have to) before 追溯到, for example:

> 这个城堡**要追溯到**罗马时代。
> (The history of) this castle dates back to Roman times.
>
> 这个家族的历史**可以追溯到**十七世纪。This family can trace its history back to the 17th century.

Comment: @Rowan please mark it as answer if it answered your question:)

Answer (score 0):

A very formal way to translate this word is “追(zhuī)朔(shuò)到(dào)”。

For example: 
中(Zhōnɡ)国(ɡuó)的(de)历(lì)史(shǐ)可(kě)以(yǐ)追(zhuī)朔(shuò)到(dào) 5000 年(nián)以(yǐ)前(qián)。
( China’s history dates back to 5000 years ago.)

Comment: The dictionary pronunciation for 溯 is su4, not shuo4, although I'm sure they're both used in practice (My pinyin IME recognizes zhuisudao and zhuishuodao as "追溯到")